# Iterate over function's output

Tags: shell, ksh

Below is the function, that gives me the directory that are greater than the value 4. (ver=4)

```
#!/bin/ksh

declare -a folders_res
declare -a dirs

check_minor_version(){
  dirs=($(find ${my_directory}/${my_dir} -type d -printf "%f\n" | sed '1d' |sort))

  for i in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    if [ "$i" -gt "${ver}" ]; then
       folders_res+=("$i")
    fi
  done

  if [ ${#folders_res[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
    echo ${ver}
  else
    echo ${folders_res[@]}
  fi
}
```

Function works as expected and gives me the output value of 5 6 7

but on calling the function output inside 'for' loop, I'm getting the following message - " unable to open file "5 6 7/my.sql" "

```
for i in "$(echo $(check_minor_version) )"; do 
 ${sqlplus} username/password@service_id << EOF
 SET WRAP OFF
 @$i/my.sql
 exit;
EOF
done
```

Is it not possible to iterate over a function's output in ksh or am I doing something silly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the quotes `"`, as follows:

```
for i in $(echo $(check_minor_version) ); do 
...
```

And also remove the `echo`, that is useless:

```
for i in $(check_minor_version); do 
...
```